# SQLite and QSqlQuery: Quoting bounded values

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt4, qsqlquery

I want to get entries' date for a given month and year, for that I execute successfully in *SQliteman* the next query:

```
SELECT date FROM Entries WHERE strftime('%Y-%m',date) = '2013-04'
```

To use this query with QSqlQuery I use the following code

```
query.prepare("SELECT date FROM Entries WHERE strftime('%Y-%m',date) = ':year-:month'");
query.bindValue(":month", QString().sprintf("%02d", month));
query.bindValue(":year", QString::number(year));
```

But the error *"Parameter count mismatch"* is raised. That is for the quotes in **:year** and **:month**, but I have to use it or the query does not return any result.

How must the query be built if the quotes cannot be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace parameters inside strings; parameters themselves are entire strings.

Concatenate the strings in SQL:

```
query.prepare("SELECT ... WHERE strftime(...) = :year || '-' || :month");
```

You could also construct the entire string beforehand:

```
query.prepare("SELECT ... WHERE strftime(...) = :yyyymm");
query.bindValue(":yyyymm", month + "-" + year);
```